# gulp-autoprefixer and gulp-sass creating infinite sass compilation loop with default gulp task

Tags: sass, gulp, infinite-loop

I'm getting an infinite sass compilation loop with the following (simplified) gulp file.

```
'use strict';

// include gulp and all plugins
var gulp         = require('gulp'),
    notify       = require('gulp-notify'),
    rename       = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass         = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps   = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


var app = {
    src: 'styles/main.scss',
    watch: 'styles/**/*.*',
    dest: 'styles/dist/'
};

// compile sass, apply autoprefixer
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    console.log('compiling SASS files')
    return gulp.src(app.src)
        .pipe(drano())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(app.dest))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write(app.dest))
        .pipe(rename('main.css'));
});

// create watch task
gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(app.watch, ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['sass','watch']);
```

When I run `gulp sass` task by itself, it's fine. But when I run the default task (`gulp`), the sass recompiles endlessly.

I really need to get autoprefixer working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are watching your destination folder. The glob `styles/**/*.*` matches every file in `styles/dist/` as well. So what happens is:

- You modify `styles/main.scss`
- `styles/main.scss` matches `styles/**/*.*` => execute `sass` task
- `sass` task generates `styles/dist/main.css`
- `styles/dist/main.css` matches `styles/**/*.*` => execute `sass` task
- `sass` task generates `styles/dist/main.css`
- `styles/dist/main.css` matches `styles/**/*.*` => execute `sass` task
- etc...

You need to exclude `styles/dist/` from your watch:

```
var app = {
  src: 'styles/main.scss',
  watch: ['styles/**/*.*', '!styles/dist/**/*'],
  dest: 'styles/dist/'
};
```

Another approach would be to limit your watch to only `.scss` files:

```
var app = {
  src: 'styles/main.scss',
  watch: 'styles/**/*.scss',
  dest: 'styles/dist/'
};
```

Whatever you do you have to make sure your watched files don't include the files in your destination directory.

Comment: That was it, Sven! It was driving me crazy. Thank you so much for your fast and accurate answer!